# Creating a dynamic link to script in php

Tags: php

I'm working on my own PHP framework and one of the things I'm trying to do is include a plugin patch, so I have my plugins path set as

```
<?php
DEFINE('USER_PLUGIN_PATH', dirname(__file__));
?>
```

Inside of `/var/www/example.org/html/application/plugins/user/index.php`
So now within my registration.php page of the plugin I have

```
$actionpage = USER_PLUGIN_PATH.'/functions.php';

<form action="<?php echo $actionpage; ?>">
```

When the form is submitted
it directs to `http://example.org/var/www/example.org/html/application/plugins/user/functions.php`, but what I would need is `http://example.org/application/plugins/user/functions.php`
is there any way to strip the `/var/www/example.org/html` from the path information so it returns what I need to run the script correctly?

Comment: simply use `plugins/functions.php` , use USER_PLUGIN_PATH while including the files in your php code, not when form submissions

Comment: Then PHP self on form submission?

Comment: That worked with the PHP SELF on form submission! Thanks Feroz!